# how to iterate through pandas row in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes in r

```
 df1 
 code     date          time       prod    price
 123      01-01-2018    06:11:00   MS      12
 123      01-01-2018    06:16:12   HS      13
 123      01-01-2018    06:17:12   HS      13
 123      01-01-2018    06:19:00   MS      12
 123      02-01-2018    06:17:12   HS      13
 123      02-01-2018    06:19:00   MS      12

 df2
 code     date         prod      price
 123      01-01-2018   MS        12
 123      01-01-2018   HS        13
 123      02-01-2018   HS        13
```

I want to filter rows from df1 and df2 with unique dates in df1. my `df1` has more than 1000 rows and `df2` has only 4 rows

e.g. 
there are 2 unique `dates` in `df1` with two unique products `MS` and `HS`. So I want to compare e.g. I want to filter date and prod `01-01-2018 & MS` rows and then compare with same date and time with `df2`

I am currently using for loop likewise

```
unique_dates = iss_trans_268559['transaction_date'].unique()   
unique_dates.sort()
unique_products = iss_trans_268559['prodcode'].unique()

for i in range(len(unique_dates)):
   current_date = df1[(df1['date'] == unique_dates[i]) & df1['prod'] == unique_products[i] 
   df2_current = df2[df2['date'] == unique_dates[i]]
```

I should get below dataframes in for loop and then i can compare the dates in `current_date` and `df2_current`

```
current_date
 code     date          time       prod    price
 123      01-01-2018    06:11:00   MS      12
 123      01-01-2018    06:19:00   MS      12

 df2_current 
 code     date         prod      price
 123      01-01-2018   MS        12
```

Problem in above loop is `i` will go out of bounds for `unique_products` and `df2` How can I do it?

Comment: Are your dataframes in R or python?

Comment: Did you consider running `drop_duplicates` on dates?

Comment: why not join the 2 dataframes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
dates= df1['date'].unique()
prods = df1['prod'].unique()

import itertools

comb = list(itertools.product(dates, prods))
# [('01-01-2018', 'MS'), ('01-01-2018', 'HS'), ('02-01-2018', 'MS'), ('02-01-2018', 'HS')]

current_date = []
df2_current = []

for i,j in comb:
    current_date.append(df1[(df1['date']==i) & (df1['prod']==j)])
    df2_current.append(df2[(df2['date']==i) & (df2['prod']==j)])
```

You can access the dataframes using `current_date[0]` and `df2_current[0]` so on...